# Editing .class file in java

Tags: java

If I replace contents of 1 class file with other , will the program execute?

There is Helloworld.class file. If I copy and paste Helloworld.class file content to Myprogram.class file.and tried executing Helloworld. will it execute?

Comment: Try it and see.

Comment: +1 to Mxyl's comment, but no it won't, it'll throw a `NoClassDefFoundError`, since it expects to find a class called Myprogram which will not be there.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it won't work (in general), since the classloader will look for a type `com.example.MyClass` in `com/example/MyClass` and find the wrong content.

Comment: Actually, since the OP said "copy and paste", presumably the original `Helloworld.class` file is still present, so it will work, and `Myprogram.class` will simply be ignored, but that doesn't make it a sensible thing to do.

Comment: If you want to "modify" a .class maybe what you are looking for is a decompiler, you can use JD-Gui. You can see the class content and if you want to modify it you can create a new java code following the decompiled class.

Answer (score 1):

It will not work.

What you are asking is essentially the same thing as renaming a class file to match that of a different name.

The JVM will throw a `NoClassDefFoundError` for the given class because it is the wrong name for the class you're trying to execute.

Java requires that filenames match the class definition, so this is essentially violating that. It's really just circumventing the fact that you would get a compiler error had you tried to name a file differently than the class defined within.